# Is there any difference between WPF TextBlock and TextBox?

Tags: wpf, textbox, textblock

What criteria must I consider when selecting one of these two controls?

Comment: Also there is [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**Common to both TextBlocks and TextBoxes:**

- Can be used to display text
- Can be set to specific Height and Width or be set to Auto so that they grow in size with the text.
- Can set font size, font type, font styling, to wrap and to range left, right or centred.
- Can have opacity set and have Pixel Shaders applied.

**TextBlock:**

- Used for displaying text more focused typographically.
- Can contain text set to different colors, fonts and sizes.
- The line height can also be increased from the default setting to give more space between each line of text.
- Text inside a TextBlock cannot be made selectable by the user.

**TextBox:**

- Used for displaying text more focused for content input or when content is needed to be made selectable by the user.
- Can only be set to one colour, one font size, one font type etc.
- Have fixed Line Spacing.
- Can also be set to a fixed height and width but also have scrollbars switched on to allow content to expand.

Comment: How is text focused? Oh, okay; it took me a while to understand that focused is describing the control, not the text.

Answer (score 23):

TextBlock is more lightweight control for displaying text and TextBox is used when you require user input or edit existing text. [Proof for mem usage](https://s22.postimg.cc/qse9gxfch/memusage.png).

Comment: Not sure if TextBlock is lighter than TextBox. Proof?

Comment: Hello Mike, sure - in terms of memory usage textbox is way heavier: 
https://s22.postimg.org/qse9gxfch/memusage.png

Comment: In case the proof image at some future point is gone. Your example shows a 14x difference in memory usage. Code used GC.GetTotalMemory(true) before and after doing a stack.Children.Add on a new textblock and textbox respectively to check how much memory differed.