# drawingContext.DrawText replacement in Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

How do I draw text using a custom fornt in C# in a Windows 8.1 Store App?

I used to do it with `drawingContext.DrawText` with `System.Windows.Media.Typeface` in my XAML applications.

Thank you!

Comment: Why is `<TextBlock Text="YourText" FontFamily="YourFont"/>` insufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that there are three control options I can use:
Textbox, TextBlock and Label.

For my application it looks like TextBlock will be the most suitable because it is lite weight and it is very customizable.

[Textblock vs Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wpf-textblock-element-and-label-control)

[Textblock vs Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204245/is-there-any-difference-between-wpf-textblock-and-textbox)