# Selecting Text inside a Multi-Inline TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some textblocks composed of Runs. I want the characters within the textblock to be individually selectable like one would expect.

Example XAML:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Cant-individually-select" />
    <Run Text="Still-Cant-individually-select" />
</TextBlock>
```

Is there any way to make the run inside the textblock behave like a standalone run? I see there a lot of solutions involving styling a TextBox to look like a TextBlock, but this isn't possible when I need multiple runs.

Comment: use a `FlowDocument`. BTW, your rep is scary.

Comment: i am using a flow document. Within my flow document I am using TextBlocks, because I want to apply a `BlurEffect` `Effect`, which you cannot apply on just straight runs.

Comment: You can not select text from TextBlock. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204245/is-there-any-difference-between-wpf-textblock-and-textbox